# Webpack not parsing riot js files

Tags: javascript, webpack, riot.js

I have recently implmented webpack in my application and trying to load all tag files which are converted into js through srcipt src tag. Still the riot js is not able to mount tag file..any solutions for the same ?

When I manually load login_form.js file, riot is able to read it correctly.

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../public/libs/riot/riot.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/dist/js.js"></script>
    <login_form></login_form>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried [riotjs-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/riotjs-loader)? It might help.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew Van Slaars produced a great video I used to get started with Riot.js + Webpack.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UgdZbT-KPpY

He also provides a "starter kit" git repo with Riot.js + webpack: https://github.com/avanslaars/riot-webpack-base

Both are very helpful and a good starting point.

The package.json shows what's required – N.B. the use of tag-loader not riotjs-loader.  I found the tag loader works for me so haven't tried the riotjs-loader.

```
{
  "name": "riot-webpack-setup",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "riot": "^2.3.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.3.17",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "tag-loader": "^0.3.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
  }
}
```

The webpack.config file is fairly simple to start with:

```
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module:{
    loaders:[
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader:'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.tag$/,
        loader: 'tag',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an official Riot tag loader for Webpack: https://github.com/riot/tag-loader

It supports hot module reloading as well.

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.tag$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'riot-tag-loader',
        query: {
          hot: false, // set it to true if you are using hmr
          // add here all the other riot-compiler options riotjs.com/guide/compiler/
          // template: 'pug' for example
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then in your code:

```
import riot from 'riot'
import 'riot-hot-reload'

// riot will have now a new riot.reload method!!
```